# how we can get audio tracks for all route nodes in that google map v2

Tags: java, android, json, google-maps, navigation

In my project , i need to make a navigation application to give the directions to a blind user,so i need to get  get audio tracks for all route nodes in that Google map. I have referenced many navigation tutorials on the web, but i didn't get what i needs. For any help, i am thankful to you.

this is my jsonparser class

```
public class DirectionsJSONParser {

/** Receives a JSONObject and returns a list of lists containing latitude and longitude */
public List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> parse(JSONObject jObject){

    List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = new ArrayList<List<HashMap<String,String>>>() ;
    JSONArray jRoutes = null;
    JSONArray jLegs = null;
    JSONArray jSteps = null;

    try {
        jRoutes = jObject.getJSONArray("routes");

        /** Traversing all routes */
        for(int i=0;i<jRoutes.length();i++){
            jLegs = ( (JSONObject)jRoutes.get(i)).getJSONArray("legs");
            List path = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            /** Traversing all legs */
            for(int j=0;j<jLegs.length();j++){
                jSteps = ( (JSONObject)jLegs.get(j)).getJSONArray("steps");

                /** Traversing all steps */
                for(int k=0;k<jSteps.length();k++){
                    String polyline = "";
                   // polyline = (String)((JSONObject)((JSONObject)jSteps.get(k)).get("polyline")).get("formatted_address");
                    polyline = (String)((JSONObject)((JSONObject)jSteps.get(k)).get("polyline")).get("points");
                    List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(polyline);

                    /** Traversing all points */
                    for(int l=0;l<list.size();l++){
                        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        hm.put("lat", Double.toString(((LatLng)list.get(l)).latitude) );
                        hm.put("lng", Double.toString(((LatLng)list.get(l)).longitude) );
                        path.add(hm);
                    }
                }
            routes.add(path);
        }
    }

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}catch (Exception e){
}

return routes;
}
/**
* Method to decode polyline points
* Courtesy : http://jeffreysambells.com/2010/05/27/decoding-polylines-from-google-maps-direction-api-with-java
* */
private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

    List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
    int lat = 0, lng = 0;

    while (index < len) {
        int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;

        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;

        LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
            (((double) lng / 1E5)));
        poly.add(p);
    }

    return poly;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are no audio tracks for directions, however it looks like you are using `Google Directions API` which if you looked at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) you would see that the instructions for the route get returned to you in the JSON as `html_instructions`.

then what you would do is use the instructions and use the `Text To Speech (TTS)` engine to say it.

**HOWEVER**

using the Directions API as turn by turn navigation is `forbidden` as explained in the `TOS`

```
Google Maps/Google Earth APIs Terms of Service

Last updated: May 27, 2009
...
10. License Restrictions. Except as expressly permitted under the Terms, or unless you
have received prior written authorization from Google (or, as applicable, from the
provider of particular Content), Google's licenses above are subject to your adherence
to all of the restrictions below. Except as explicitly permitted in Section 7 or the
Maps APIs Documentation, you must not (nor may you permit anyone else to):
...
10.9 use the Service or Content with any products, systems, or applications for or in
connection with:

(a) real time navigation or route guidance, including but not limited to turn-by-turn
route guidance that is synchronized to the position of a user's sensor-enabled device;

and may be disabled for certain apps (somehow, at least on Android)... FromGeocode
scraping in .NET conversation:
This is not allowed by the API terms of use. You should not scrape Google Maps to
generate geocodes. We will block services that do automated queries of our servers.

Bret Taylor
Product Manager, Google Maps
```